# Ipython script stop on shell error

Tags: ipython

Does ipython have a setting similar to ['-e' in bash](http://ss64.com/bash/set.html) that stops the execution of the script if any [ipython's shell command](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access) returns a non-zero value?

Comment: Had any luck finding something else than checking manually for errors after each shell command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, no. However, after a `!foo` shell command, the exit code is stored as the value `_exit_code`. So your script could check that and throw an error.

For some reason, on my system it multiplies all the exit codes by 256. I'm not at all sure why it's doing that.